# libGDX and Box2D - Which black sorcery causes this bug?

Tags: java, debugging, libgdx, box2d

I am using the latest version of libGDX.
I created a body, that I want to make travel back and forth between 2 points called initialPosition and finalPosition, which are Vector2.

I store these two Vector2 in an array called travel. To make the body go from one point to the other, I use an int called step : When the body reaches travel[step], I change the value to 0 or 1, depending on its previous value (0 or 1)

So basically, in the constructor, after building the body I have :

```
travel = new Vector2[2];
travel[0] = initialPosition;
travel[1] = finalPosition;

step = 1;
direction = new Vector2();
direction = new Vector2(travel[step].x - body.getPosition().x, travel[step].y - body.getPosition().y);
body.setLinearVelocity(direction.clamp(speed, speed));
```

And in the render I have :

```
System.out.println("initialPosition = " + initialPosition.toString());

if(!new Vector2(travel[step].x - body.getPosition().x, travel[step].y - body.getPosition().y).hasSameDirection(direction)){

    if(step > 0)
        step = 0;
    else step = 1;

    direction = new Vector2(travel[step].x - body.getPosition().x, travel[step].y - body.getPosition().y);
    System.out.println("Direction change");     
}

body.setLinearVelocity(direction.clamp(speed, speed));
```

So, here is the problem : The behavior was absolutely not what I wanted. Once the body reaches the finalPosition, instead of going back to the initialPosition, the body just jerks around the finalPosition.

Thus, I did many control, and I noticed that the initialPosition was changing during the process. I monitor it's value with the ligne

```
System.out.println("initialPosition = " + initialPosition.toString());
```

**Where becomes really weird :**
if I change the render code with

```
System.out.println("initialPosition = " + initialPosition.toString());

if(!new Vector2(travel[step].x - body.getPosition().x, travel[step].y - body.getPosition().y).hasSameDirection(direction)){

}

body.setLinearVelocity(direction.clamp(speed, speed));
```

I have the exact same problem, while the `if` statement is empty !
But if I remove the `if(){}`, I have this code :

```
System.out.println("initialPosition = " + initialPosition.toString());

body.setLinearVelocity(direction.clamp(speed, speed));
```

The problem is gone : The initialPosition keeps its original value.

**Where it becomes even weirder**
If in the render I put only this code

```
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("initialPosition = " + initialPosition.toString());
    System.out.println("body.getPosition() = " + body.getPosition().toString());
```

The initialPosition change again ! While the render does nothing more than printing things in the console !
And thank to the separator ------ that I print at each step, I can see that on the first step, the initialPosition keeps its value and the body.getPosition() changed, which is normal because right after the creation of the body I applied to it a linear velocity. And at the next step, the initialPosition took the previous value of the body.getPosition() and the body.getPosition() changed again, and so on.

Does anyone have an idea what is happening here ?

Comment: Where did you initialize the initialPosition and how? `travel[0] = initialPosition;` after this line, both `travel[0]` and  `initialPosition` refer to the **same Object**. OK you didn't change any of its value anywhere else but it is possible that you made the same mistake somewhere else.

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot this important point. Right after the body creation, I initialize initialPosition `initialPosition = body.getPosition();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like I said before in the comments `initialPosition = body.getPosition();` after this line they refer to the same Object.

See the source code of the [body.getPosition](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-box2d/gdx-box2d/src/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Body.java) and the javadoc: `Note that the same Vector2 instance is returned each time this method is called.`

To change this behaviour Initialize initialPosition like this:

```
tempPosition = body.getPosition();
initialPosition.x = tempPosition.x;
initialPosition.y = tempPosition.y;
```